# How to properly switch GIT branches and return to later work.

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm still trying to wrap my head around working on multiple branches on my local machine and being able to switch back and forth.

I'm working on Branch X, updated 4 files. Now I'm being asked to switch gears and work on Branch Y. I'm not ready to push the changes in Branch X. What do I do?

In the past, I thought that's what stash is for. `git stash`, checkout branch Y, and then later come back to branch X and `git stash apply` and I should be back where I started.

However, I recently did that and screwed things up doing this:

- `git stash` branch X
- checked out branch Y, modified files
- `git stash` branch Y
- checked out branch X
- `git stash apply` on branch X and...from what I can tell, my stash from branch Y got applied to branch X.

So I'm quite confused. Is what happened above what was supposed to happen? Should I have been doing some commits in the process?

Comment: Stashes aren't on branches, you're just pushing to and popping from a stack of change sets. Yes, that's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so a stash is kind of a 'master pile' of changes and isn't actually segregated by branch. That would explain why what happened happened. As such, what is the proper way to switch branches while keeping the changes to that particular branch?

Comment: @DA It's a stack, rather than a pile.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that with Git, your changes and branches are yours until you push them somewhere else. So it's perfectly safe, and even a great idea, to commit your local changes as soon as you've done a quantum of work (you can always `rebase` and squash them later).

In your case, here's what you could have done (even though branch `X` wasn't "ready"):

```
git add .
git commit -a -M'WIP: (describe where you are)'
git checkout Y
```

Branch `X` on your remotes stays as it is, but your local work is safe. No one else will see it unless you `push` it to a remote.

If you want to keep `X` in its last-clean state, just check out a new branch and add your commits to it:

```
git checkout -b pick-a-descriptive-name-for-the-branch
git commit ...   # commits land on this new branch
git checkout Y
```

Now `X` is as it was before you started making the latest set of changes, `pick-a-descriptive-name-for-the-branch` has the changes you were in the middle of, and `Y` is unaffected.

You can easily `cherry-pick` the last commit on `pick-a-descriptive...` to `X` when you're ready to continue work:

```
git checkout pick-a-descriptive-name-for-the-branch
git log -1 # Note the SHA1 of the commit, which is your work in progress
git checkout X
git cherry-pick -n SHA1
```

This will take the changes from the last commit on `pick-a-descriptive-name-for-the-branch`, and add them to `X` without committing them.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash apply` will apply that most recently stashed changes.  I suspect what you wanted was to apply a specific stash.  You can view your stashes with `git stash list` and apply a specific one with `git stash apply stash@{N}`.

You can also name your stash with `git stash save "some name"` so they're easier to find later on.

Also note, that `git stash apply` keeps the stash in the stash list.  If you no longer need the stash after applying, look into `git stash drop` or `git stash pop`.

Comment: oh! interesting. I wasn't aware of the naming option! That obviously helps!